# Do I need to close directories if I use using namespace boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator or not?

Tags: c++, boost

For example I have this code. I use `recursive_directory_iterator`. Do I need to close directories in this cycle or boost do it automatically?

```
void selective_search( const path &search_here, const std::string &exclude_this_directory)
{
    using namespace boost::filesystem;
    recursive_directory_iterator dir( search_here), end;
    while (dir != end)
    {
        // make sure we don't recurse into certain directories
        // note: maybe check for is_directory() here as well...
        if (dir->path().filename() == exclude_this_directory)
        {
            dir.no_push(); // don't recurse into this directory.
        }

        // do other stuff here.            

        ++dir;
    }
 }
```

Comment: In general, C++ APIs always use the RAII pattern (which is a bit of a misnomer, because the real essence is that destructors reliably free up resources potentially held by classes). The RAII pattern is superior because it prevent accidental omission, even in the most complicated control flows (like when exceptions are raised)

Answer (score 1):

Closing manually is not necessary. Directory iterator closes each entry when it is no longer needed.